# Change text on hover, then return to the previous text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a system of comments, and each comment has a button that normally displays the number of replies to it. I want that when a user hovers over the button, the text changes from "3 replies" to "Reply!", and then, when the mouse leaves the button, the text returns to "3 replies".

Because the number of replies varies for each comment, I cannot do a simple mouseover/mouseout script. One way to go around it would be to pass the number of replies as a variable, and make a small function to take care of it. But there must be a simpler way. I tried using the :hover thing in css to change the content of the tag (with the css property content), but no luck yet.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a bad design. How will a user surmise that they should hover the text that tells them how many replies there are to initiate a reply of their own? Instead of relying upon the text itself, wrap it inside of a span and target that element.

Comment: @MetalFrog The text has the appearence of a button, I don't think that it would take too much time to understand.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Yes, you can use CSS `content`. To switch between the normal text and "Reply!", put the normal text in a `span` and hide that when hovering.

```css
button {
  width: 6em
}

button:hover span {
  display: none
}

button:hover:before {
  content: "Reply!"
}
```

```html
<button><span>3 replies</span></button>
```

Edit: this works in IE8, but not in its compatibility mode, so I assume IE7 is out. Would that be a problem?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be a problem. Thanks, very simple solution.

Comment: For some reason it didn't work for me. Changing `:before` to `:after` helped.

Answer (score 46):

I think this would be a straightforward way to go for it. Use two span inside your button, one with content 'x replies', one with content 'Reply!'. Using CSS and :hover, you switch which span is shown on hover.

```css
button .comment {
  display: none;
}

button:hover .replies {
  display: none;
}

button:hover .comment {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<button>
    <span class="replies">5 Replies</span>
    <span class="comment">Reply!</span>
</button>
```

This works just fine in about everything, as it uses very basic things to achieve an equally basic goal.

Comment: Best solution to support i18n.

Comment: I really like this format, keeps the wording in the markup and the styling int he CSS - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#button_id').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).text('Reply!');
    },
    function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'script.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: comment_id,
            success: function(num_replies){
                $('#button_id').text(num_replies + ' replies');
            }
        });
    }
);
```

I think you could use this kind of function, when you stop hovering, you feed the ajax call your comment id, and it returns the # of replies for that comment.  You can decide how you want to store/retrieve your comment ID.

Comment: As I said, the number of replies varies with each comment, so this function won't do the trick.

Comment: what stores the number a replies? a database?  Probably could put an ajax call function to grab the # of replies.

Comment: The number of replies can be queries from the database, but I prefer to avoid that, as the number is already on the page!

Comment: how is this number stored on the page?  a JS variable?

Comment: It isn't stored in the page, but rather, it is displayed on it. When the page loads, each comment is displayed together with the number of replies. I wanted to change the number of replies for "Reply!", and then back to the number of replies, without having to re-query it.

Comment: Yeah looks like Mr. Lister has a good solution, but just for reference, anything on the web page can be recorded as a JS variable, and then the simple `$('#').hover` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a combination of jQuery [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and jQuery [.data():](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

http://jsfiddle.net/5W4Bd/

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">default text</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('#myDiv')
    .data('textToggle', 5)
    .hover(function (e) {
        var that = $(this);

        // get the text from data attribute
        var textToSet = that.data('textToggle');

        // save the current text so it can be reverted
        that.data('textToggle', that.text());

        // set the new text
        that.text(textToSet);
    }, function (e) {
        var that = $(this);

        // get the text from data attribute
        var textToSet = that.data('textToggle');

        // save the current text so it can be reverted
        that.data('textToggle', that.text());

        // set the new text
        that.text(textToSet);
    });
```

edit: feel free to refactor the anonymous function used as the two callbacks to hover, since they are exactly the same :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I thought that using the data() function was very elegant, so I was trying to make your function work, but Mr. Lister posted a simpler solution.

Comment: @LFS nice, i did not even know about that content attribute!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it, is to create two spans with the button, and have classes for each span.

```
<button>
  <span class="replies">3 Replies</span>
  <span class="comments"></span>
<button>
```

Leave the second one empty, and in css, write:

```
button{ 
  //your decorative code here }

button:hover .replies{
   display: none; }

button:hover .comments:before{
   content:"Reply!"; }
```

This is similar to first answer, but that answer doesn't always work with a preprocessor like SASS, or LESS.

Answer (score 2):

In modern browsers you could also use **:after** pseudo element for changing the text on hover.

```css
.label             { width:5em }
.label:after       { content:'Hello'; }
.label:hover:after { content:'World'; }
```

```html
<button class="label"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants to try the same on menu links, (different language text on hover):

```css
span {
  font-size: 12px;
}

a {
  color: green;
}

a:hover span {
  display: none;
}

a:hover:before {
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
  content: "ಕನ್ನಡ";
}
```

```html
<a align="center" href="#"><span>kannada</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

As simple as it might be:

```
$('.controls button.filter').hover(function(){

    var original = $('#current_filter').text();
    var descr = $(this).attr("title");

    $('#current_filter').html( descr );

}, function() {

    $('#current_filter').text(original);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to change the content in Html.

```css
.contact .contact-number {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transition-duration: .3s;
}
.contact:hover .contact-text {
    opacity: 0;
    transition-duration: .3s;
}

.contact:hover .contact-number {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-duration: .3s;
}
.contact-number,
.contact-text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 18px;
    top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <span class="contact-text">contact us</span>
  <span class="contact-number">9981010848</span>
</div>
```