# Jquery text change on hover with transition

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

For this HTML snippet :

```
<header>
<h1>Title</h1>
<h2>my first sentence</h2>
</header>
```

I run this Jquery script :

```
$('header h2').hover(function(){
    $(this).text("my second sentence");
}, function() {
    $(this).text("my first sentence");
});
```

I would like to add a fade in / fade out transition between the two states.

I tried adding .fadeIn("slow") and .fadeOut("slow") just after $(this) but it does not work. Could you bring me some help please ?

PS : i'm using JQuery instead of CSS :hover because CSS :before(content) trick does not work with transition : cf. [Change text on hover, then return to the previous text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913293/change-text-on-hover-then-return-to-the-previous-text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$( function() {
var fs = $('h2').text();
var ss = 'my second sentence';
$('h2').hover(function(){
    $(this).hide().text(ss).fadeIn("slow");
}, function() {
    $(this).hide().text(fs).fadeIn("slow");
});
});
```

For fadeIn() you need to hide() that element first. I declared two variables not necessary but will help you. `var fs` (first sentence) and `var ss` (second sentence).

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ssFpH/)

Comment: It looks like fadeIn does not work here. And there is another problem : it does not behave like CSS :hover

Comment: have you added `$(document).ready( function() { });` in your code? and what css hover ?

Comment: i've just done it : `my first sentence
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
$('h2').hover(function(){
    $(this).hide().text("my first sentence").fadeIn("slow");
}, function() {
    $(this).hide().text("my second sentence (for hover)").fadeIn("slow");
});
});
</script>`

Comment: I said css :hover because i'd like mouseout = return to previous text.

Comment: Here is what happens with your script : when mouseover, nothing changes, after mousever (i've become mouseout), the text changes to "my second sentence (for hover)". When i come back to mouseover, the text returns to "my first sentence".

Comment: I have edited my post because the code was messy. My own code did not correspond to what I wanted. Sorry !

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest:

```
// find the relevant element(s)
// assign the current text to a custom data-* attribute (for later)
$('header h2').attr('data-originalText', function () {
    // using this not $(this), since a jQuery object requires more 'work'
    return (this.textContent || this.innerText).trim();
}).hover(function () {
    // fading out the current element, replacing the text and then fading back in
    $(this).fadeOut(600, function () {
        $(this).text('my new sentence!').fadeIn();
    });
},
function () {
    // fading out the current element, replacing the text (from the data-* attribute)
    // and fading back in
    $(this).fadeOut(600, function () {
        $(this).text($(this).attr('data-originalText')).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VnDDB/).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).
- [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).
- [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).
- [`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It looks a bit more complicated than Aqib's, but the references are a very educational way ! (-:

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This also removes any hover flicker one might experience sometimes with longer strings