# Using pseudo class selectors to change content?

Tags: css

How can I change the text which is contained in `<p>` tags by using CSS's pseudo class selectors?

For example, when I hover over a paragraph, the content of paragraph must change to what would be specified in `p:hover` selector.

Comment: The `content` property is only meant to work on pseudo elements.  You aren't supposed to be able to change the entire contents of an element via CSS (such as a paragraph tag), though some browsers do allow it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change text on hover, then return to the previous text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913293/change-text-on-hover-then-return-to-the-previous-text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/4xcw7/304/)

---

One way is to use `p:hover:before` along with the `content` attribute.

Here's an example:

**Html:**

```
<p>
<span>First text!</span>
</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
p:hover span {
  display:none
}
p:hover:before {
  content:"Second text appears instead!";
  color:red;
}
```

If you'd like to know more about the `content` property, check out this nice little [**article**](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/).

Comment: Easy simple solution +1. :) I was wondering though, just as my own little curiosity what the point of the `content` property or attribute is? It seems like it has more purpose rooted in the scripting world rather than the styling one. Don't know if you know right off hand.

Comment: @War10ck This nice little article might help you out there - http://css-tricks.com/css-content/

Answer (score 1):

Zenith has a simpler solution, but the following allows you to put formatting in your "hover" content. Try the following HTML:

```
<p>
  <span class="normalDisplay">Text to display <em>usually</em>.</span>
  <span class="hoverDisplay">Text to display on <em>hover</em>.</span>
</p>
```

and the following CSS:

```
p .hoverDisplay {
    display: none;
}
p .normalDisplay {
    display: inline;
}
p:hover .hoverDisplay {
    display: inline;
}
p:hover .normalDisplay {
    display: none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wNb7/)