# On hover change text, and then replace with original text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, var

I've very limited JS knowledge but have got this far.

On the hover of the DIV it is changing the text as i wish, but I also want it to change back when i finish the hover.

Been fiddling all day but I can't seem to figure it out.

Code is as follows.

```
<div class="involved-share">
  <p>share</p>
</div>
```

and the script

```
$('.involved-share').hover(function() {

var $p = $(this).find('p');
var txt_old = (this.textContent || this.innerText).trim();

$p.fadeOut(300, function () {

        $p.text('with others').fadeIn();
    });


});
```

I want to return the original text back to the container.

Any suggestions?

Comment: check this answer may be you can do it with css http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913293/change-text-on-hover-then-return-to-the-previous-text

Answer (score 2):

You are provided with few javascript solutions but I would recommend CSS here. It would be as simple as:

```css
.involved-share:hover .hover,
.involved-share .hover-other {
    display: none;
}
.involved-share:hover .hover-other {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="involved-share">
    <p class="hover">share</p>
    <p class="hover-other">with others</p>
</div>
```

Not only it's more natural to handle hover effects with CSS but it's also much more flexible because you don't have to modify you javascript code if you decide to change text on the page.

Answer (score 2):

maybe just css

```css
.involved-share:before {
  content: 'share';
}
.involved-share:hover:before {
  content: 'hover state for share';
}
```

```html
<div class="involved-share">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary operator for toggling the `textContent`:

```
$('.involved-share').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    var text = e.type === 'mouseleave' 
               ? 'share'
               : 'with others';

    $('p', this).stop().hide().text(text).fadeIn();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9asoxc56/

If there are more than one `.involved-share` element on the page that have different textContents you should store the original and new contents somewhere. `data-*` attribute can be a good option.

```
<div class="involved-share">
  <p data-original="share"
     data-nue='with others'>
       share
   </p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.involved-share').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('p', this).stop().hide().text(function() {
        return e.type === 'mouseleave' 
               ? $(this).data('original')
               : $(this).data('nue');
    }).fadeIn();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3hna9o6L/

Answer (score 1):

```js
   
   $(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.involved').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).find('span').text('Mouse Enter');
  }).mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).find('span').text('Mouse Leave');
   });
});
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="involved"><span>share</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : add one more `function()` for hover end event and replace `originalText` for the `p` element

```
var originalText = $('.involved-share p').text();

$('.involved-share').hover(function() {

var $p = $(this).find('p');

$p.fadeOut(300, function () {
    $(this).text('with others').fadeIn(300);
});  
}, function(){
  // set original text
  $(this).find('p').fadeOut(300,function(){
    $(this).text(originalText).fadeIn(300);
  });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9asoxc56/4/)**

Comment: Thanks, all working good.
however how would i get the original text to fade back in?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a CSS and HTML only approach!

HTML:

```
<div class="involved-share">
  <span class="default-txt">share</span>
  <span class="ommited-txt">with others</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.default-txt {
    display: inline;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .3s;
}

.ommited-txt {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s;
}

.involved-share:hover .ommited-txt {
    display: inline
    opacity: 1;
}

.involved-share:hover .default-txt {
    display:none;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

In that way you maintain content in HTML markup and visual behavior in CSS