# How do I change span ID text on hover? (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I want to change the "sample text1" to "sample text2" on hover. Is this possible in CSS?
My current code is this:

```
span#hUp::before {
  content: "sampletext1";
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Here's an edit so you can understand the situation better:

```
<span id="hUp" style=right;margin-right: 5px;margin-top: 3px;font-size: small;">
  ::before
  <a href="mailbox.php?id#">Mailbox</a>
</span>
```

I want to change the `::before` element upon hovering.

Comment: and what does that code do, and why is that wrong or insufficient?

Comment: This is simply adding text to a header, it doesn't do anything apart from displaying text. Everything works like intended, but I want the text to change when you hover on it.

Comment: Seems to me like a duplicate of this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913293/change-text-on-hover-then-return-to-the-previous-text/9913526

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm getting it correctly, this is what you want:

```css
span#hUp::before {
  content: "sampletext1";
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
span#hUp:hover::before {
  content: "sampletext2";
}
```

```html
  <span id="hUp" style="right;margin-right: 5px;margin-top: 3px;font-size: small;">
    <a href="mailbox.php?id#">Mailbox</a>
  </span>
```

Not a lot to explain, you want when you `:hover` on `span#hUP` to change the `::before`, so the selector is `span#hUp:hover::before`

Comment: Check the snippet. It does work. Do you have something else you have not mentioned that may be messing with that?

Comment: I put the code in the wrong line - now it works! Thanks a lot with the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
span#hUp::before::hover {
   content: "sampletext2";
}
```

`before::hover` gets called when you hover your mouse over that element.

Comment: It must before on hover. `span#hUp:hover:brefore {...`

Answer (score 0):

try this **updated code**

```css
#hUp {width:6em}
#hUp a:hover span{display: none;
}
#hUp a:hover:before {
  content: "sampletext1";
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: monospace;
 }
```

```html
<span id="hUp" style="right;margin-right: 5px;margin-top: 3px;font-size: small;">
  <a href="mailbox.php?id#"><span>Mailbox</span></a>
</span>
```