# How do I change the text when hovering over a div element and link

Tags: html, css, button, hover

This is my code for now,
Id like it to say ADD when hovering

```
.b:hover {
    background:  white;
    color:rgb(180, 179, 179) ;
}
 
.b:hover a {
    background:white;
    color: rgb(180, 179, 179);
}
.b a {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 98%;
}
```

```
<div id="b1"; class = b>
    <a href="test.html">9.99€</a>
</div>
```

tried everything that i know off

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that like this, here by hovering, the initial text will be replaced by the new text.

You have to use both `.b a:after`  and  `.b a:hover:after`.

```css
.b:hover {
    background:  white;
    color:rgb(180, 179, 179) ;
}
.b a:after {
    content: '9.99€';
}
.b a:hover:after {
  content: "new Text"
}
```

```html
<div id="b1"; class ="b">
    <a href="test.html"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do so like this:

```
<div id="b1"; class = b>
    <a href="test.html"></a>
</div>
```

```
.b a {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 98%;
}

.b a:after {
    content:'9.99€';
}

.b a:hover:after {
    content:'ADD';
    background:white;
    color: rgb(180, 179, 179);
}
```

But I think cleaner solution is to use button as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913293/change-text-on-hover-then-return-to-the-previous-text)